# Table of contents, chapter titles, section titles, etc.. are centered and chapter titles start in the middle of the page

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, thesis

I am beginning my Thesis and this is only the second time I've used TEX.  I'm not sure how to get my Table of Contents, Chapter Titles, Sections and Subsections to appear on the left indent.  In addition, the table of contents and chapters all begin near the center of the page instead of at the top.  Is this just how the thesis document is default?  If so, is there a way to change these defaults?

Here is my code (pulled all the packages from a friend's dissertation. not sure which are actually needed or not):

```
\documentclass[print,double]{thesis}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  backref=page,
  unicode=true,
  urlcolor = blue,
  colorlinks = true,
  citecolor = blue,
  linkcolor = blue]{hyperref}

%\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt} 
%\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{}{;} 

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\date{Date}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Motivation}

\chapter{Thin Film Optical Semiconductors}
    \section{Material Properties}
    \section{Synthesis}
        \subsection{Substrate Cleaning}
        \subsection{Reactive Ion Sputtering}
        \subsection{Atomic Layer Deposition}

\chapter{Thin Film Characterization}
    \section{Profilometry}
    \section{X-Ray Diffraction}
    \section{Sepctroscopic Ellipsometry}

\chapter{Ultrafast Laser Induced Damage}
    \section{Kelydsh Theory}
    \section{Photoionization}
        \subsection{Multiphoton Ionization}
        \subsection{Tunnelling Ionization}
    \section{Avalanche Ionization}

\chapter{Matlab Modeling of Absorption Phenomena in Optical Semiconductors}
    \section{Parameterization Techniques}
    \section{Multiphoton Versus Tunnelling Ionization}
    \section{Electron Density Rate Equations}

\chapter{Analysis}
    \section{Model Simulation Versus Experimental Results}
        \subsection{Gallinium Arsenide}

\chapter{Future Work}
    \section{Evolve Model to include Recombination Methods}
    \section{Aquire Experimental Data for Additional Optical Materials}
    \section{Fitting of Parameters within Model to Experimental Data}

\end{document}
```

Appreciate any help someone may provide!!!
-Chris

Comment: Can you edit your question and Ctrl-K your source code so that it is formatted as such?

Comment: Where did you get the file `thesis.cls` (implied by the line `\documentclass[print,double]{thesis}`, where `.cls` indicates the 'document class' file)?  It is responsible for determining how the first page of a chapter looks unless you load another package or packages to modify that behaviour.  Moreover, *if* that class is properly designed for your school, then it is possibly already doing the right thing with respect to the thesis guidelines set out by your school.  (That is a big 'if', however.)

Comment: You do know you are procrastinating, right? If you are just beginning your thesis, worrying about the formatting is a sure sign of this. (I know this from personal experience.) Apart from anything else, your graduate school could change their guidelines before you submit in which case you'll just have to redo it later. Moreover, many graduate schools have loopy requirements which will require hacks that you cannot put in place until you've basically finalised the content. All you care about at this point is producing clear, reasonably laid out text for you and your advisers.